# Scaling mechanism in Creality Slicer 1.2.3 for super small/large STL

Tags: creality-ender-3, slicing, creality-cr-10, stl

I am having a tough time to understand scaling out and in STD files loaded into the **Creality Slicer 1.2.3**.
For instance an STL like this:

```
 facet normal -nan -nan -nan
  outer loop
  vertex -0.0515186 0.0260341 0.0015
  vertex -0.0514094 0.0260341 0.0015
  vertex -0.0516411 0.0260341 0.00172995
  endloop
 endfacet
```

This STL is super small, considering that the default unit for STL is a millimetre, but when I open it in the Creality Slicer it shows me that the model is much larger.

I assume there is some scaling mechanism in the slicer (also for large STL). Do you know how it works? It seems to me that there are some rules. For example, if the max length of the facet is < 0.05, the slicer changes the unit to meters(?).

Comment: All STL files I download from e.g. Thingiverse makes me scale the object with 1/10 in Fusion360, so the default must be cm.